# Plotting barchart on States map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot

Following is USA states example data from state.x77 dataset in r:

```
mydf = structure(list(usa_state = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"), class = "factor"), 
    Life.Exp = c(69.05, 69.31, 70.55, 70.66, 71.71), HS.Grad = c(41.3, 
    66.7, 58.1, 39.9, 62.6)), .Names = c("usa_state", "Life.Exp", 
"HS.Grad"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> mydf
   usa_state Life.Exp HS.Grad
1    Alabama    69.05    41.3
2     Alaska    69.31    66.7
3    Arizona    70.55    58.1
4   Arkansas    70.66    39.9
5 California    71.71    62.6
>
```

I want to plot it on USA states map. I can plot the map using following code:

```
all_states <- map_data("state")
ggplot() + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="gray", fill="white" )
```

[image]

But I am not able to plot barcharts over the map. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to learn that there are three distinct 2d plotting paradigms in R.

Comment: Some further details regarding this from an experienced person like you will be much appreciated.

Comment: @mso - have you had a chance to see if my answer below will be of any help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already upvoted it. However, as you can see, the boundaries of USA or its states are not seen in your answer output map. People would prefer colors to be filled in whole map with state boundaries as I have posted in my question above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plots on a map using ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028659/plots-on-a-map-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

I drew on two great sources to answer this:

- http://www.r-bloggers.com/us-state-maps-using-map_data/. Especially see the gist https://gist.github.com/4252133 and comments at end from @amandamasonsingh  (although the gists demo prison dataset is not available)
- [ggplot/mapping US counties — problems with visualization shapes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714052/ggplot-mapping-us-counties-problems-with-visualization-shapes-in-r)

**SOLUTION**

```
mydf <- structure(list(usa_state = 
                         structure(1:5,
                                   .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"), class = "factor"), 
                      Life.Exp = c(69.05, 69.31, 70.55, 70.66, 71.71), 
                      HS.Grad = c(41.3, 66.7, 58.1, 39.9, 62.6)),
                 .Names = c("usa_state", "Life.Exp", "HS.Grad"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(RColorBrewer) # lots of color palettes for these kind of charts

library(data.table) # for sorting by key
library(mapproj) #coord_maps() needed this

all_states <- map_data("state")

# You need to merge dataset with maps one with long and lat.
# But you need same key so lets change state to region used in maps all_states
# Note I lowercased it to get the match

mydf$region <- tolower(mydf$usa_state)
totaldf <- merge(all_states, mydf, by = "region")

# switched to data.table to fix the cut up map issue
# getting sort by region then order 
totaldt <- as.data.table(totaldf)
setkey(totaldt, region, order)

ggplot(data = totaldt, 
       aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = HS.Grad)) +
  geom_polygon() + coord_map() +
  scale_fill_gradientn("", colours=brewer.pal(9, "GnBu"))
```

**DONT FORGET TO SORT ME**

If your data is not sorted correctly by region and then by order, then you will get patchy maps like this.

[image: sliced up map]

I use `data.table` package and key the data. Also data.table is much faster if you need to merge lots of data. You use format X[Y] for this. See data.table [cheatsheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) if you are new to this package.

**FINAL MAP**

This is for the `HS.Grid` in your example. Get your other chart by changing the `fill = myvariable`

[image: map example for HS.grid]

Note not all the states are shown, because the test data is limited to these states. In a fuller example you will see more states.

Also you will see Alaska is missing. Its not in the maps - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26541278/4606130) from @jazzurro for practical tests on state names with setdiff.