# Maps, ggplot2, fill by state is missing certain areas on the map

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps

I am working with `maps` and `ggplot2` to visualize the number of certain crimes in each state for different years. The data set that I am working with was produced by the FBI and can be downloaded from their site or from [here](http://www.hofroe.net/stat579/crimes-2012.csv) (if you don't want to download the dataset I don't blame you, but it is way too big to copy and paste into this question, and including a fraction of the data set wouldn't help, as there wouldn't be enough information to recreate the graph).

The problem is easier seen than described.

[image: Robbery by state]

As you can see California is missing a large chunk as well as a few other states. Here is the code that produced this plot:

```
# load libraries
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

# load data
fbi <- read.csv("http://www.hofroe.net/stat579/crimes-2012.csv")
fbi <- subset(fbi, state != "United States")
states <- map_data("state")

# merge data sets by region
fbi$region <- tolower(fbi$state)
fbimap <- merge(fbi, states, by="region")

# plot robbery numbers by state for year 2012
fbimap12 <- subset(fbimap, Year == 2012)
qplot(long, lat, geom="polygon", data=fbimap12,
  facets=~Year, fill=Robbery, group=group)
```

This is what the `states` data looks like:

```
    long      lat     group order  region subregion
1 -87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>
2 -87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>
3 -87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>
4 -87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>
5 -87.57087 30.32665     1     5 alabama      <NA>
6 -87.58806 30.32665     1     6 alabama      <NA>
```

And this is what the `fbi` data looks like:

```
    Year Population Violent Property Murder Forcible.Rape Robbery
1 1960    3266740    6097    33823    406           281     898
2 1961    3302000    5564    32541    427           252     630
3 1962    3358000    5283    35829    316           218     754
4 1963    3347000    6115    38521    340           192     828
5 1964    3407000    7260    46290    316           397     992
6 1965    3462000    6916    48215    395           367     992
   Aggravated.Assault Burglary Larceny.Theft Vehicle.Theft abbr   state region
1               4512    11626         19344          2853   AL Alabama  alabama
2               4255    11205         18801          2535   AL Alabama  alabama
3               3995    11722         21306          2801   AL Alabama  alabama
4               4755    12614         22874          3033   AL Alabama  alabama
5               5555    15898         26713          3679   AL Alabama  alabama
6               5162    16398         28115          3702   AL Alabama  alabama
```

I then merged the two sets along `region`. The subset I am trying to plot is

```
      region Year Robbery      long      lat group
8283 alabama 2012    5020 -87.46201 30.38968     1
8284 alabama 2012    5020 -87.48493 30.37249     1
8285 alabama 2012    5020 -87.95475 30.24644     1
8286 alabama 2012    5020 -88.00632 30.24071     1
8287 alabama 2012    5020 -88.01778 30.25217     1
8288 alabama 2012    5020 -87.52503 30.37249     1
       ...            ...    ...      ...
```

Any ideas on how I can create this plot without those ugly missing spots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played with your code. One thing I can tell is that when you used `merge` something happened. I drew states map using `geom_path` and confirmed that there were a couple of weird lines which do not exist in the original map data. I, then, further investigated this case by playing with `merge` and `inner_join`. `merge` and `inner_join` are doing the same job here. However, I found a difference. When I used `merge`, order changed; the numbers were not in the right sequence. This was not the case with `inner_join`. You will see a bit of data with California below. Your approach was right. But `merge` somehow did not work in your favour. I am not sure why the function changed order, though.

```
library(dplyr)

### Call US map polygon
states <- map_data("state")

### Get crime data
fbi <- read.csv("http://www.hofroe.net/stat579/crimes-2012.csv")
fbi <- subset(fbi, state != "United States")
fbi$state <- tolower(fbi$state)


### Check if both files have identical state names: The answer is NO
### states$region does not have Alaska, Hawaii, and Washington D.C.
### fbi$state does not have District of Columbia.

setdiff(fbi$state, states$region)
#[1] "alaska"           "hawaii"           "washington d. c."

setdiff(states$region, fbi$state)
#[1] "district of columbia"

### Select data for 2012 and choose two columns (i.e., state and Robbery)
fbi2 <- fbi %>%
        filter(Year == 2012) %>%
        select(state, Robbery)
```

Now I created two data frames with `merge` and `inner_join`.

```
### Create two data frames with merge and inner_join
ana <- merge(fbi2, states, by.x = "state", by.y = "region")
bob <- inner_join(fbi2, states, by = c("state" ="region"))

ana %>%
    filter(state == "california") %>%
    slice(1:5)

#        state Robbery      long      lat group order subregion
#1  california   56521 -119.8685 38.90956     4   676      <NA>
#2  california   56521 -119.5706 38.69757     4   677      <NA>
#3  california   56521 -119.3299 38.53141     4   678      <NA>
#4  california   56521 -120.0060 42.00927     4   667      <NA>
#5  california   56521 -120.0060 41.20139     4   668      <NA>

bob %>%
    filter(state == "california") %>%
    slice(1:5)

#        state Robbery      long      lat group order subregion
#1  california   56521 -120.0060 42.00927     4   667      <NA>
#2  california   56521 -120.0060 41.20139     4   668      <NA>
#3  california   56521 -120.0060 39.70024     4   669      <NA>
#4  california   56521 -119.9946 39.44241     4   670      <NA>
#5  california   56521 -120.0060 39.31636     4   671      <NA>

ggplot(data = bob, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = Robbery, group = group)) +
geom_polygon()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks @jazzurro, works great. Any idea what ```inner_join``` is doing differently than ```merge```?

Comment: @epwalsh I revised my answer. Have a look. `merge` and `inner_join` do the same job. But the former messed up the column, order. You will see it above.

Comment: interesting... I guess ```inner_join``` is more robust.

Comment: @epwalsh I am not sure what is happening. But, `inner_join` is doing the right thing for you. If you would face a similar situation in the future, you may want to avoid `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the order of arguments to **merge**

```
fbimap <- merge(fbi, states, by="region")
```

has the thematic data first and the geo data second. Switching the order with

```
fbimap <- merge(states, fbi, by="region")
```

the polygons should all close up.