# In R, How to manipulate (using manipulate pkg) the ggplot "fill" variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this as a starting point: [ggplot/mapping US counties — problems with visualization shapes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714052/ggplot-mapping-us-counties-problems-with-visualization-shapes-in-r)

I wanted to add a manipulate control for the fill variable. Something similar to this:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, XLConnect, rgdal, RColorBrewer, data.table, mapproj, manipulate)

#additional lines
county.data[obesity.data,obesity09:=PCT_OBESE_ADULTS09]
county.data[obesity.data,obesity10:=PCT_OBESE_ADULTS10]
county.data[obesity.data,obesity13:=PCT_OBESE_ADULTS13]

manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=ObesityYear)) +
scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))+
geom_polygon()+coord_map()+
labs(title="2010 Adult Obesity by County, percent",x="",y="")+
theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker("obesity09", "obesity10", "obesity13"))
```

But of course, the ggplot does not recognize the ObesityYear variable as part of the dataframe and gives the error:

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ObesityYear' not found

> EDIT AFTER COMMENTS LED TO RESOLUTION

```
manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x='long', y='lat', group='group', fill=ObesityYear)) + 
    geom_polygon()+coord_map()+ 
    theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker('obesity09', 'obesity10', 'obesity13'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you need to use `aes_string` in order to be able to use string choices in the `picker` function.

Look at this example:

```
#example data.table
set.seed(5)
dt <- data.table(a = runif(10), 
                 b = runif(10), 
                 fillvar1 = factor(sample.int(2,20, rep=T)), 
                 fillvar2 = factor(sample.int(2,20, rep=T)),
                 fillvar3 = factor(sample.int(2,20, rep=T)))
```

Solution:

```
library(manipulate)
manipulate({   
    ggplot(dt, aes_string('a', 'b', colour=choose_var )) + geom_point()},
    choose_var = picker('fillvar1','fillvar2','fillvar3'))
```

It is hard to upload a picture to show the interactivity but you will notice in the above code that every time you select a different value, the colours of the points will change accordingly.

Comment: `fill` would work in the exact same way, but I cannot use it with `geom_point`.

Comment: This won't work because the fill requires a continuous variable from the dataframe.  I tried your suggestion:
Replaced aes with aes_string:
manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=ObesityYear)) +
scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))+
geom_polygon()+coord_map()+
labs(title="2010 Adult Obesity by County, percent",x="",y="")+
theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker("obesity09", "obesity10", "obesity13"))

Which resulted in: Error in lapply(x, f) : object 'long' not found

Comment: My example would work with continuous variables too. You are using the function wrong. The point of using `aes_string` is to use it with strings. Using `x=long` will not work because `long` is not a string. You should use `x='long'` and the same for all the variables in the `aes_string` function...

Comment: It should be: `manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x='long', y='lat', group='group', fill=ObesityYear)) + scale_fill_gradient("",colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))+ geom_polygon()+coord_map()+ labs(title="2010 Adult Obesity by County, percent",x="",y="")+ theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker("obesity09", "obesity10", "obesity13"))`

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'm banging my head trying to get this to work. 
Now I get:
Error in continuous_scale("fill", "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low, high,  : 
  unused argument (colours = c("#FFFFCC", "#FFEDA0", "#FED976", "#FEB24C", "#FD8D3C", "#FC4E2A", "#E31A1C", "#BD0026", "#800026"))

Comment: This is a completely different part of your code. Try running the `manipulate` part with only the `ggplot` function and the `geom` function. If it works it means that the problem is not in the manipulate but in another part of your code, in which case you should ask a different question.

Comment: This works:
manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x='long', y='lat', group='group', fill=ObesityYear)) + 
    geom_polygon()+coord_map()+ 
    theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker('obesity09', 'obesity10', 'obesity13'))

Comment: @PouyaYousefi There was probably a mistake in `continuous_scale` then. I suggest you post a new question with a reproducible example so that we can help you solve your problem.