# Error in continuous_scale when using scale_fill_gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbrewer

In a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212359/in-r-how-to-manipulate-using-manipulate-pkg-the-ggplot-fill-variable)

The following works fine:

```
manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x='long', y='lat', group='group', fill=ObesityYear)) + 
    geom_polygon()+coord_map()+ 
    labs(title="2010 Adult Obesity by County, percent",x="",y="")+ 
    theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker("obesity09", "obesity10", "obesity13"))
```

But this produces an error:

```
manipulate({ggplot(map.df, aes_string(x='long', y='lat', group='group', fill=ObesityYear)) + 
    geom_polygon()+coord_map()+
    scale_fill_gradient("",colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))+
    labs(title="2010 Adult Obesity by County, percent",x="",y="")+ 
    theme_bw()}, ObesityYear = picker("obesity09", "obesity10", "obesity13"))
```

Error:

```
Error in continuous_scale("fill", "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low, high,  : 
  unused argument (colours = c("#FFFFCC", "#FFEDA0", "#FED976", "#FEB24C", "#FD8D3C", "#FC4E2A", "#E31A1C", "#BD0026", "#800026"))
```

Comment: You are specifying the colors the wrong way. When using `scale_fill_gradient`, you have to specify a `low` value and a `high` value. See also `?scale_fill_gradient`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction:
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"), guide="colorbar")